# Understanding ``stdin: true tty: true`` on a kubernetes container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have been readying here and there online but the answer does not come thoroughly explained. I hope this question here if answered, can provide an updated and thorough explanation of the matter.

Why would someone define a container with the following parameters:

```
stdin: true
tty: true
```

Also if

```
`docker run -it`
```

bind the executed container process to the calling client stdin and tty, what would setting those flag on a container bind its executed process it to ?

I could only envision one scenario, which is, if the command is let say bash, then you can **attach** to it (i.e. that bash running instance) later after the container is running.

But again one could just run `docker run it` when necessary. I mean one launch a new bash and do whatever needs to be done. No need to attach to a running one

So the first part of the question is:

a) What is happening under the hood ?

b) Why and when to use it, what difference does it make and what is the added value ?

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK, setting `stdin: true` in container spec will simply keep container process stdin open waiting for somebody to attach to it with `kubectl attach`.

As for `tty: true` - this simply tells Kubernetes that stdin should be also a terminal. Some applications may change their behavior based on the fact that stdin is a terminal, e.g. add some interactivity, command completion, colored output and so on. But in most cases you generally don't need it.

Btw `kubectl exec -it POD bash` also contains flags `-it` but in this case this really needed because you're spawning shell process in container's namespace which expects both stdin and terminal from user.