# Kubernetes v1.25 is giving me "unable to use a tty - input is not a terminal" error but v1.22 didn't

Tags: kubernetes, ssh

**Situation**

At work, we have been using Kubernetes Service Mesh v1.22 for the past year, and all was fine. We lately debuted a 2nd environment, this time running v1.25. This introduced several security related changes that we had to overcome, but that is a separate issue.

**Problem**

My problem is that a script that works perfectly on 1.22 isn't working on 1.25. The script is ran on your local, logins into the 1.22 instance, kubectl execs -it into a pod, opens an interactive session, and the terminal session remains open. You are now free to navigate around the pod to your hearts content. The purpose of the script is to go straight from local terminal to pod, bypassing all the tedious steps to get there manually.

I run that same script in 1.25 environment and I get the following error: "unable to use a tty - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file".  If I perform these steps manually (login to environment via password, kubectl exec -it into pod), everything is fine. I can console in via /bin/sh  successfully. I just can't do it via this script from my local.

**Code**

```
sshpass -p $password ssh -t $kubernetes-login "pwd && echo '$password' | sudo -S kubectl exec -it $pod  -c $container -n $namespace -- /bin/sh"
```

**Troubleshooting**

-A previous [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915849/understanding-stdin-true-tty-true-on-a-kubernetes-container) said to edit the helm chart under spec/container so that tty and stdin: true. Got same error

-Instead of 'sudo -S kubectl exec -it', I try using 'sudo -S kubectl exec --stdin=true --tty'. got same error

**Thoughts**

-Could the fact that v1.25 is forcing sudo basically at all times and v1.22 didn't mean something? Maybe TTY has conflicts? Again, when I do these steps manually, including using the mandatory sudo, things are fine

-The syntax of the code is correct. It's been thoroughly tested and used in other scripts, so the only problem segment is the -t after exec -i. Simply doing exec -i and replacing 'ls' for /bin/sh will show you the contents of the pod just fine. Just no interactive sessions.

-The pwd is proof that you logged into the environment correctly and password got acknowledged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sshpass -p $password ssh -t $kubernetes-login "pwd && echo '$password' | sudo -S kubectl exec -it $pod  -c $container -n $namespace -- /bin/sh"
```

The input for the `kubectl` command is the pipe (`|`) from the `echo`, even though the content of that pipe is processed by sudo. That pipe is not a tty, so you can't format the command that way. You're going to need a different way of getting the password into `sudo` so the input isn't changed to the pipe.

You can tell sudo to request the password from a helper command, so

```
sudo -A /path/to/passwd kubectl exec -it $pod  -c $container -n $namespace -- /bin/sh
```

I believe the `-A` flag only takes a command, and not something parsed by a shell with args, so you may need to make the password injection a script.

Another option, if sudo remembers a previous auth for some timeout, is to split the commands like:

```
sshpass -p $password ssh -t $kubernetes-login "pwd && (echo '$password' | sudo -S true) && sudo kubectl exec -it $pod  -c $container -n $namespace -- /bin/sh"
```

Comment: THANKS!!! The second code (splitting commands in 2) works perfectly for me. I would have never have though of that